# AJAX inserting NULL values into MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

My HTML script gathers the latitude & longitude and sends them to another PHP script via ajax, which inserts those values into mysql, problem is that AJAX inserts NULL values into the table. It's inserting values of "0.000000" for both Latitude & Longitude, lat & long are type float(10,6) in the DB as stated by the internet for best practice with gps coords. I'm obvious new developer please help -- HTML Script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AJAX DATABASE</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">



    /*/ Wait for Cordova to load
    /*/
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var watchID = null;

    // Cordova is ready
    //

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds
        var options = {enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 3000, maximumAge:0};
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

    }


    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {    


        var latitude = document.getElementById("lat");
        latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = document.getElementById("longitude");
        latitude.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
        insertDB(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.latitude);
    }

    // onError Callback receives a [PositionError](PositionError/positionError.html) object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Options: throw an error if no update is received every 30 seconds.
    //
    var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000 });




    // Sends latitude & longitude value to php script and alerts on success

    function insertDB(latitude, longitude){
        var xttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = 
                this.responseText;
                alert("state changed by ajax")
            }

        }
        xttp.open("GET", "ConnectTest.php? 
         latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude, true);
        xttp.send();
    }




    </script>


  </head>
  <body>

    <p id="lat"></p><br>
    <p id="longitude"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the PHP --

```
<?php 


    //POST VARIABLES


    $one = $_GET['latitude'];
    $two = $_GET['longitude'];

    //ESTABLISH CONNECTION 

    $servername = "localhost:3306";
    $user = "client";
    $pass = "sonic_client";

    $db_name = "sonicstrains";

    $server = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $pass, $db_name);




    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'latitude' = ".$two;

    $result = mysqli_query($server, $sql);

    if(!isset($_GET['latitude'])){
        echo "Nothing is set";

    }

    if(!$server){

        die("Connetion error".mysqli_connect_error());

    }else{

        if (!$result){

            $insert = "INSERT INTO users (latitude, longitude) VALUES ('$one', '$two')";
            mysqli_query($server, $insert);
            echo "Coordinates Inserted";

        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: You're putting the parameters in the *URL*, which means you need to use `$_GET` to access them. The fact that you used `POST` in your code is irrelevant in this case. POST params always go in the body of the request, you are `send()`ing an empty body. You should also look into `fetch`, which will make your obsolete code a lot simpler.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. You want 0.0000? you want null?

Comment: Big help, but my longitude isn't posting for some reason. still posting 0.000, know why? I changed both params in php to $_Get['foo']

Comment: @SonicStrains you are passing only latitude value in function insertDB(latitude). You need to pass both latitude and longitude value 

function insertDB(latitude, longitude)

Comment: I updated the function to include longitude, but only the latitude is posting still

Comment: @SonicStrains From where are you calling this function insertDB(latitude,  longitude)? are you passing both values in insertDB(25.123, 71.233)?

Comment: The onSuccess() in the HTML, I'm passing position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude in the params for insertDB()

Answer (score 0):

Replace the xttp open and send functions with below:

```
    xttp.open("POST", "ConnectTest.php, true);
    xttp.send(latitude="+latitude+"&longitude="+longitude);
```

Comment: Your solution made the script stop inserting values, please post your code if it works. Using the URL to post values worked but for some reason only my longitude didn't update. (using the above code)

Comment: Still not working, only latitude is posting to mysql

Comment: I guess you changed from $_POST to $_GET in PHP. So, now there are multiple mismatches in both files. First, either you use Get, then change xttp.open('POST' to xttp.open('GET' and Second in the sql query you are passing longitude value in where clause instead latitude and, Third change the isset to too $_GET